# drupal 7 db_select options

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal

Based on the API of drupal

```
db_select($table, $alias = NULL, array $options = array())
```

I would like to ask what is the use of options and how it can be uses. Seems like most sources is ignoring this field. I am hoping to make use of the concept of "Object relational mapping". One object to each database table and add relation to their objects via annotation in PHP.

So I just wanna know if it is possible via drupal 7's API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$options` array seems to go all the way down to [`DatabaseConnection::$connectionOptions`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/property/DatabaseConnection%3A%3AconnectionOptions/7), which is simply:

> The connection information for this connection object.

Basically, unless you're scratching your head and thinking "how do I get this option into the database connection string?", you don't need to be using the `$options` array.

To answer your second question, no, Drupal has no ORM functionality.

There was a [module](http://drupal.org/project/orm) for mapping CCK fields in an ORM fashion for Drupal 6, but it hasn't been touched in a while. There's also no Drupal 7 port, and the DB layer changed so much from D6 - D7 that I doubt any of that will be salvageable.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will build an ORM myself as a module then. I was just thinking if there is an easier way to do it.